# Can I place an 8x PCIe 2.0 Promise EX8760T into the 16x PCIe 2.0 slot on my Asus P7H55-M/CSM?

Tags: motherboard, raid, computer-building, compatibility, pci-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will a PCI Express x1 TV tuner work on a PCI Express x16 slot ?](https://superuser.com/questions/242130/will-a-pci-express-x1-tv-tuner-work-on-a-pci-express-x16-slot)

The Promise card has a PCIe 2.0 8X interface, and the motherboard has a single PCIe 2.0 16x slot.

My questions is:
Even though the PCIe 2.0 16x slot on the motherboard is generally intended to be used for graphics, can I expect other types of PCIe 2.0 cards to function in that slot?

I am planning on using only the onboard video processor for display, and I need the RAID adapter in this server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work.  PCIe will use disable what ever lanes are not in use.  The 16x slot isn't dedicated to graphics in anyway - it is the same as any other PCIe slot.  It's just that the only PCIe cards most use are graphics cards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes a PCIE 8x card will work in a PCIE 16x slot, the slots are entirely backwards compatible. Wikipedia backs this up:

> A PCIe card will fit into a slot of its physical size or larger, but may not fit into a smaller PCIe slot. Some slots use open-ended sockets to permit physically longer cards and will negotiate the best available electrical connection.

[Source](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/PCI_Express)