# Physical obstacle plugging PCIe 4x into PCIe 8x

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, pci-express, adapter

I know this has been already discussed, for example [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/242872/can-i-place-an-8x-pcie-2-0-promise-ex8760t-into-the-16x-pcie-2-0-slot-on-my-asus), where there's even a wikipeida quote saying that it's possible.

So, according to that, I bought [that PCIe 4x card](http://www.asus.es/Motherboards/Accessories/U3S6/). I have two PCIe 2x slots and four PCIe 8x ports. I was planning to plug it into one of the PCIe 8x.

But when I was going to plug it in, I realised the PCIe 8x ports are in the wrong direction... I mean, they're phisically "looking at" the hard drives zone, the small portion of the slot is not the closest to the peripheral side of the box.

I'm not sure I achieved to express my problem, so don't doubt to ask for clarification. Which should be the solution? Is there any kind of adapter that could solve my problem?

Here is my motherboard:
[image: old motherboard]

Comment: What motherboard are you using?

Comment: A picture of inside of your motherboard, particularly PCIe slots would be helpful.

Comment: [It's that](http://news.mydrivers.com/Img/20101008/03453840.jpg). I'm even thinking that this disposition of the PCI 8x is common, but I have never figured out how can a normal card with external plugs be connected to them

Comment: Ah..you can not take a higher level card and put it into a lower pci e slot. a X4 card will fit in a X4, X8 and X16 slot, but not a x1 slot. Same with a pcie x16  card will not fit into a PCIe x8 slot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit after your motherboard picture:

The two small black slots are PCIe x1 slots and this will only accomodate a PCIex1 card. The large slot with a tab on the back is PCIe x 16. It can accomodate PCIe x1, x4, x8 and x16. You can put a lower PCIe x# card into a the same or larger size PCIe slot, just not the other way around.

If the "small part" of the slot is facing away from the I/O panel, then you are looking at PCI slots, not PCI express.
[image: pci vs pcie]

The PCI express x 1 (black small slots on your motherboard) will not accomodate a PCIe x4 card.

Comment: Ok, I'm freaking... First of all lots of thanks. Second, I can't understand how could I live so many years convinced that they were PCIe 8x... So embarrasing

Comment: There are pcie x1, x4, x8 and x16. You would be able to fit a x4 card into a x4, x8 or x16. You can always go up, you can not go back. For example, you can not put a pcie x16 card into a pcie x8 slot.

Comment: I know, now I realize they are PCI, I know my options are just a PCIe 1x riser adapter, and I know I won't get all the full speed. Thanks again.

Comment: I've not actually seen physical x8 slots tho - most seem to be x16 running at x8. I'd also note the PCI ports are put there so that should you use a 2 slot video card, it won't block a PCIe slot, but rather a 'useless' pci slot. Most desktops have one x16, one or two x16 running at x8, and one x1. Mine has a single PCI slot under near a x8/16 but YMMV. I've as such seen neither a x4 or x8 slot - you're expected to use a x16 slot for those.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - good points

Comment: There are two more options: 1x Cut parts of the PCIe x4 card (scary, but works if you cut from the right end).  Or file open the end of the PCIe x1 slot. That will allow you to fit the x4 card in the x1 slot. Which will work, albeit at x1 speeds. Neither are common tasks, but I wanted to mention them for completeness sake.

Comment: @Hennes OMG I'll definitely buy [that](http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Express-Profile-Extension-PEX1TO162/dp/B0039XPS5W) before cutting the hardware piece - as far as I can understand, it won't be able to run at 4x ever more.

Comment: Aye. I would never do [this (picture of a card with cut off 'pins')](http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e44/Direwolf007/Violated.jpg). It still works though.